# Partially applied function doesn't work in Scala

Tags: scala

Why I can't invoke `g2` with the second parameter in the line `g2(1, _: Int)(9)`?

`g2(1, _: Int)` returns a function `<function1>` and then I invoke that `<function1>` with parameter. At the same time in the example above I can invoke `f3(9)` however it is the same as `g2(1, _: Int)(9)` IMHO.

```
// OK

def f1: (Int, Int) => Int   =   _ + _
val f2: (Int, Int) => Int   =   f1
val f3: (Int) => Int        =   f2(1, _: Int)

println {
  f3(9)
}

// FAIL

def g1: (Int, Int) => Int   =   _ + _
val g2: (Int, Int) => Int   =   g1

println {
  g2(1, _: Int)(9) // Error: 'g2' does not take parameters 
}
```

Comment: To get it work I need to add parentheses: `(g2(1, _: Int))(9)` which is weird.

Comment: does `(g2(1, _: Int))(9)` work? scala has multiple parameter lists, so `f(x)(y)` might parse differently from `(f(x))(y)`. I'm not sure how that interacts with the wildcard (`f(x, _)`), though

Comment: Yeap, as I said with parentheses it works.

Comment: @Finkleson I only saw your comment after finishing mine ;)

Comment: You could also write `g2(1, _: Int).apply(9)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's the issue with the scope of underscore in anonymous functions. See here for the rules: [What are the rules to govern underscore to define anonymous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125850/what-are-the-rules-to-govern-underscore-to-define-anonymous-function)

According to the rule 1 from the link above `g2(1, _: Int)(9)` is interpreted as `(x: Int) => g2(1, x)(9)`. So you need to add parentheses, for the rule 2 to start working: `(g2(1, _: Int))(9)`

Comment: Wouldn't that be precedence, not scope?

Answer (score 1):

As you add in a comment, `(g2(1, _: Int))(9)` works.

Scala has multiple parameter lists, so `f(x)(y)` parses differently from `(f(x))(y)`. As `g` takes only one parameter list, it can't take the second parameter list, hence the explicit grouping is necessary.

`g2(1, _: Int)(9)` means: take the function `g2(x, y)(z)`, and apply parameters `x = 1, z = 9`.

`(g2(1, _: Int))(9)` means: take the function `g2(x, y)`, and apply parameter `x = 1`. Then apply `y = 9` to the resulting function.