# How to call this Scala function when "error: Unit does not take parameters"

Tags: scala, function

When I define this function, I can call it without a problem:

```
scala> val c = (_: String) + "sd"
c: String => String = <function1>

scala> c("1")
res13: String = 1sd
```

However if I let the above function `print` the result without returning it, I have the following error:

```
scala> val b = print((_: String) + "sd")
<function1>b: Unit = ()

scala> b("1")
<console>:26: error: Unit does not take parameters
       b("1")
        ^
```

I know the system method `print` returns `Unit` type, but shouldn't the function `b` be a function that can be called with an argument as I defined? **Why the above `b` function can not be called with `b("1")`?**

How to understand and solve the problem? Thank you.

Comment: Notice how the console returned `<function1>b: Unit = ()` for the second case. You did `val b = print(yourFunction1)` and since `print` returns a `Unit` (after printing the provided thing), it printed `<function1>` (which is the toString for a Function1) and then `Unit` was assigned to your `b`.

Comment: `val b = (s:String) => print(s + "sd")`

Comment: The question is now why is `_` not recognised as Input. Are there any rules when it is recognised and when it isn't?

Comment: I think I know the reason now. The reason is *"The placeholder syntax for anonymous functions replaces the smallest possible containing expression with a function."* In my case in the deifnition of `b`, `(_: String) + "sd"` as such is a `<function1>`. So `b` is not a function, it only prints the function1 and returns Unit as @SarveshKumarSingh says. Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627117/scala-underscore-error-missing-parameter-type-for-expanded-function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, as you have already discovered

```
print((_: String) + "sd")
```

expands to

```
print((x: String) => x + "sd")
```

instead of the desired

```
(x: String) => print(x + "sd")
```

because `_` binds to the [innermost expression delimiter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28126068/5205022) `()` or `{}`.

Comment: Which is one of the reasons I always recommend newcomers to avoid the `_` syntax. It is not always clear how it is expanding, it may introduce subtle bugs and finally simple lambda is always more readable due the named parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following sequence.

An anonymous function from `String` to `String`.

```
scala> (_: String) + "sd"
res0: String => String = $$Lambda$1156/0x00000008406c1040@6b8bdcc6
```

Print the `String` representation of the anonymous function.

```
scala> println((_: String) + "sd")
$line10.$read$$iw$$iw$$$Lambda$1158/0x00000008406c3040@31f5b923
```

Print the `String` representation of the anonymous function. Save the result in variable `b`.

```
scala> val b = println((_: String) + "sd")
$line11.$read$$iw$$iw$$$Lambda$1159/0x00000008406a7040@173cfb01
b: Unit = ()
```

The `print()` and `println()` passed parameter is call-by-reference, not call-by-name, so it is fully evaluated at the call site before being passed to `print()`. In this case `print()` receives a function, it doesn't become part of a larger function.