# Error for parentheses in higher order function definitions (Scala)

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, higher-order-functions, parentheses, scala-placeholder-syntax

I am facing error with round brackets in high-order definition. The following code works fine:

```
val foo: Int => (Int => Int) = n => n + _*2
```

However, after adding parentheses compiler error arises

```
val foo1: Int => (Int => Int) = n => n + (_*2)

Error:(34, 56) missing parameter type for expanded function ((<x$5: error>) => x$5.$times(2))
```

I am aware that I could use another style to avoid error:

```
val bar = (x: Int) => (y: Int) => x + (y*2)
```

I interested what is the problem with parenthesis and how to use them correctly in the same style of formatting high-order functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first case of anonymous function placeholder parameter

```
val foo: Int => (Int => Int) = 
  n => n + _ * 2
```

expands to

```
val foo: Int => (Int => Int) =
  (x: Int) => (n: Int) => n + x * 2
```

whilst the second

```
val foo1: Int => (Int => Int) = 
  n => n + (_ * 2)
```

expands to

```
val foo1: Int => (Int => Int) = 
  n => n + (x => x * 2)
```

which is a syntax error. The key is to understand the [scope of underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28126068/5205022):

> If the underscore is inside an expression delimited by () or {}, the
>   innermost such delimiter that contains the underscore will be used;

Comment: Wow, that's good to know. Is there a workaround for that if I had to use parentheses? Suppose I want to do this: `val foo: Int => (Int => Int) = (x: Int) => (n: Int) => (n + x) * 2`

Comment: The workaround for when you cannot use placeholder syntax is to not use placeholder syntax.