# How to pass Function result to math.max

Tags: scala, scala-placeholder-syntax

I am able to do this:

```
  def largestAt(fun: (Int) => Int, inputs: Seq[Int]):Int = {
    inputs.reduceLeft(math.max(_,_))
  }
```

But, when I am trying to do this:

```
def largestAt(fun: (Int) => Int, inputs: Seq[Int]):Int = {
   inputs.reduceLeft(math.max(fun(_),fun(_)))
}
```

I am getting below mentioned compilation error:

```
overloaded method value max with alternatives:
[error]   (x: Double,y: Double)Double <and>
[error]   (x: Float,y: Float)Float <and>
[error]   (x: Long,y: Long)Long <and>
[error]   (x: Int,y: Int)Int
[error]  cannot be applied to (Int => Int, Int => Int)
[error]     inputs.reduceLeft(math.max(fun(_),fun(_)))
```

I just want to pass the result of the `fun` to `math.max` call. How can I achieve this.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Note that there is also `maxBy`: `inputs.maxBy(f)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anonymous function placeholder parameter syntax in the expression

```
inputs.reduceLeft(math.max(fun(_),fun(_)))
```

expands to something like

```
inputs.reduceLeft(math.max(a => fun(a), b => fun(b)))
```

and `max` does not take a pair of functions as input. Instead, you are likely after something like

```
inputs.reduceLeft((a, b) => math.max(fun(a), fun(b)))
```

On the other hand the following usage of underscore works

```
inputs.reduceLeft(math.max(_, _))
```

because it expands to

```
inputs.reduceLeft((a, b) => math.max(a, b))
```

Placeholder syntax should probably be used judiciously, and the key to using it correctly is understanding the [scope of underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28126068/5205022):

> If the underscore is inside an expression delimited by () or {}, the
>   innermost such delimiter that contains the underscore will be used;

Comment: The trick is to stop using it for anything that is not a simple expression _(like `foo.map(_.x)` or `bar.reduce(_ + _)`)_. If I would get a dollar everytime someone have a problem because they used the `_` syntax...