# Scala sortWith for java.sql.Timestamp sometimes will or won't compile when using two underscores

Tags: scala

I'm confused why a type that `implements comparable` isn't "implicitly comparable", and also why certain syntaxes of `sortWith` won't compile at all:

```scala
// The iter is a collection of records, each event_time is a java.sql.Timestamp

// A. Works but won't sort eq millis
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith(_.event_time.getTime < _.event_time.getTime)

// B. Doesn't compile, implements comparable yet not implicitly comparable?
val records = iter.toArray.sortBy(r => (r.event_time))

// C. Doesn't compile, complains about the 2nd _ though it's like the first line
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith(_.event_time.before(_.event_time))

// D. Doesn't compile, also complains though it's more like the first line
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith(_.event_time.compareTo(_.event_time) < 0)

// E. Works, sorts by epoch millis, then nanos after the milli.
val records = iter.toArray.sortBy(r =>
    (r.event_time.getTime, r.event_time.getNanos))
// But this leaves questions about the above uses of sortWith which don't work
```

Given that the first line works, using two underscores, I don't understand why the compiler complains about the other uses of sortsWith. Is there some syntax which could use the `before` method happily? And using timestamp's comparable status somehow with **line B**?

Maybe I should note I'm using Scala 2.11.12 with JDK 8, because it's for a specific version of Spark on a deployment of AWS EMR.

I can see that with Scala 2.13.6 **line B** compiles and works,
however with 2.11.12 I'm getting:

```
No implicit Ordering defined for java.sql.Timestamp.
not enough arguments for method sortBy: (implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[java.sql.Timestamp])List[Playground.Foo].
Unspecified value parameter ord.
```

[image: Captured error from 2.11.12]
I'm unclear how to satisfy what it's requesting.

Then the error **line C** gives me is:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$5) => x$5.event_time.before(((x$6) => x$6.event_time)))
```

While **line D** is similar with:

```
missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$7) => x$7.event_time.compareTo(((x$8) => x$8.event_time)).$less(0))
```

As noted by an answer below, C and D can be accomplished with another syntax:

```scala
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith{case(a,b)=>
              a.event_time.before(b.event_time)} // C
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith{case(a,b)=>
              a.event_time.compareTo(b.event_time) < 0} // D
```

Which has gotten me to fixing all the ways shown except **line B** in 2.11.12 (see https://scastie.scala-lang.org/xAwV3FheQWu8n7OoaZaQGA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Works but won't sort eq millis
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith(_.event_time.getTime < _.event_time.getTime)
```

This is because `Timestamp.getTime` does not include millis.

```
// Doesn't compile, implements comparable yet not implicitly comparable?
val records = iter.toArray.sortBy(r => (r.event_time))
```

Not sure why you think it does not work. [Works fine](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/eUxpVkW4RgmX4FwzTGCtvw) for me ...
(BTW, you got too many ugly parentheses there. This is better written as
`sortBy(_.event_time)`.

```
// Doesn't compile, complains about the 2nd _ though it's like the first line
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith(_.event_time.before(_.event_time))
```

Yes, these underscore placeholders only work at the immediate scope level.
This expression above translates to something like

```
   .sortWith(x => x.event_time.before(y => y.event_time))
```

which is, of course, invalid.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28125850/what-are-the-rules-to-govern-underscore-to-define-anonymous-function) for the description of how underscores are interpreted within context.
When in doubt, just declare the variable explicitly:

```
.sortWith { case(a,b) => a.event_time.before(b.event_time) }
```

```
// Doesn't compile, also complains though it's more like the first line
val records = iter.toArray.sortWith(_.event_time.compareTo(_.event_time) < 0)
```

Same reason/same fix as above

Comment: I guess I should have said, due to working with a specific EMR and spark build in using Scala 2.11. With jdk 8, maybe a later update resolved some of these. Thanks for the case(a,b) suggestion fix.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an implementation of `compare` by extending `Ordering` for the type is one work around (in Scala 2.11.12) for the issue with **line B**:

```scala
import java.sql.Timestamp

case class Record(event_time: Timestamp) extends Ordered[Record] {
  def compare(that: Record) = this.event_time.compareTo(that.event_time)
}

def correct(records: List[Record]) = (
  if ((records.head compare records.last) < 0) " C" else " Inc"
) + "orrectly ordered"

val now1 = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis())
now1.setNanos(999000001)
val now2 = new Timestamp(now1.getTime())
now2.setNanos(999999999)
val records_in:List[Record] = new Record(now2) :: new Record(now1) :: Nil

// A. Works but won't sort eq millis
val records_outA = records_in.sortWith(_.event_time.getTime < _.event_time.getTime)
println("A: " + records_outA + correct(records_outA))

// B. Doesn't compile, implements comparable yet not implicitly comparable?
//val records_outB = records_in.sortBy(r => (r.event_time))
// B. Works by relying on Record class's definition of Orderable
val records_outB = records_in.sorted
println("B: " + records_outB + correct(records_outB))

// C. Doesn't compile, complains about the 2nd _ though it's like the first line
//val records_outC = records_in.sortWith(_.event_time.before(_.event_time))
// C. Works by changing argument to use explicitly named parameters
val records_outC = records_in.sortWith((a,b)=>a.event_time.before(b.event_time))
println("C: " + records_outC + correct(records_outC))

// D. Doesn't compile, also complains though it's more like the first line
//val records_outD = records_in.sortWith(_.event_time.compareTo(_.event_time) < 0)
// D. Works by also changing argument to something else without implicit parameters
val records_outD = records_in.sortWith{case(a,b)=>a.event_time.compareTo(b.event_time) < 0}
println("D: " + records_outD + correct(records_outD))

// E. Works, sorts by epoch millis, then nanos after the milli.
val records_outE = records_in.sortBy(r =>
    (r.event_time.getTime, r.event_time.getNanos))
println("E: " + records_outE + correct(records_outE))
```

The [above produces](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jsNkZ5XQTeqqlalwPS1HeQ):

```
A: List(Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999999999), Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999000001)) Incorrectly ordered
B: List(Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999000001), Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999999999)) Correctly ordered
C: List(Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999000001), Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999999999)) Correctly ordered
D: List(Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999000001), Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999999999)) Correctly ordered
E: List(Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999000001), Record(2021-06-14 23:19:12.999999999)) Correctly ordered
```